# Hibernate or HQL Select on the result of another SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Is there a way using HQL on the following query?

`SELECT userId, pwd, pwdDate FROM
    (SELECT userId, AES_DECRYPT(pwd, 'key_str') as pwd, pwdDate
    FROM  UserHistory order by pwdDate desc limit 5 ) AS A
    WHERE pwd = :pwd`

The following worked.

`SELECT *
    FROM  UserHistory order by pwdDate desc limit 5`

The above sql can be the following in hibernate.

`Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserHistory.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("pwdDate"));
    List<UserHistory> list = criteria.setMaxResults(5).list();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked. The key is to createSQLQuery for Native SQL.

```
String SQL = 
"SELECT A.* FROM \n" +
"(select * \n" +
" from user_history$ order by pwdDate desc limit 5 ) AS A \n" + 
"where pwd = AES_ENCRYPT(:pwd, 'key_str') \n";

Query query = session.createSQLQuery(SQL);
query.setParameter("pwd", psw);
List<UserHistory> list = query.list();
```